# SharePoint 2010 Delete items in List

Tags: c#, list, sharepoint

Is there any way to delete items in a list/library from SharePoint 2010 but not only based on date created (default information policy options) but also on a combination of columns values in this list.

Thank you

Comment: more explanation please

Comment: using code ...? form your question correctly

Comment: And is it asp-classic (VBScript) or c# (asp.net)?

Comment: You should move this question to http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can delete items based on specific column values:

```
    SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
    SPList list = web.Lists["List1"];
    SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
    // create query for example that Title=xyz & FirstName=abc 
    query.Query = "<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Text'>xyz</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='FirstName' /><Value Type='Text'>abc</Value></Eq></And></Where>";
    // get all items as per query which will going to be delete
    SPListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(query);

    int itemCount = list.ItemCount;
    for (int k=0; k<itemCount; k++)
    {
        SPListItem item = listItems[k];
        listItems.Delete(k);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I used the same logic but using XML in a batch

Comment: Got the solution ?